# Size of first pdf page is not large as other pdf page using itext in liferay

Tags: pdf, liferay, itext, liferay-6

My requirement was to develop an application to read data from user_ table which is one of the default table present in  liferay default database lportal and publish that data in pdf format.
 Each and every thing is working fine but when I was try to increase the size of pages then except first page all other pages size increases according to my need. I don't know why this is happening and why only first page size is not increases.
my action class code is

```
 public class pdfPortlet extends MVCPortlet 
  { 
  public void serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res)
  throws PortletException, IOException 
{
    if(req.isUserInRole("administrator"))
    {
        try 
        {
            adminMethod(req,res);
        }
        catch (PortalException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SystemException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (DocumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        userMethod(req,res);
    }
}



   /**********            adminMethod which can fetch the whole user data from user_ table         
   * @throws SystemException 
   * @throws PortalException 
   * @throws DocumentException 
   * @throws IOException **********/

   public void adminMethod(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res) throws PortalException, SystemException, DocumentException, IOException
   {
   int numOfUser=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();                                                                  //get the number of users

String remoteUserId = req.getRemoteUser();                                                                          //getting current user id
Integer io=Integer.parseInt(remoteUserId);                                                                          //getting current userid
int currentUserId=io.intValue();                                                                                    //typecasting from Integer to primitive int
User tblUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(currentUserId);                                                         //will return an object containing element of each row and hence by iterating this element we can get number of columns
                                                                                                                    System.out.println("@@@@@@  tbluser: "+tblUser);
req.setCharacterEncoding(StringPool.UTF8);
com.lowagie.text.Document document = new com.lowagie.text.Document();   //blank pdf created 
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);                      //predefine class PdfWriter calls static method getInstance
//document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(2000, 2600));
document.open();                                                //open pdf in write method
PdfPTable table= new PdfPTable(39);                         //creating a pdf table having 39 columns  
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(2000, 2600));
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
/*  float[] columnWidths = new float[39];
for(int i=0;i<39;i++)
    columnWidths[i]=10f;
table.setWidths(columnWidths);*/

table.addCell("uuid_");
table.addCell("userId");
table.addCell("companyId");
table.addCell("createDate");
table.addCell("modifiedDate");
table.addCell("defaultUser");
table.addCell("contactId");
table.addCell("password_");
table.addCell("passwordEncrypted");
table.addCell("passwordReset");
table.addCell("passwordModifiedDate");
table.addCell("digest");
table.addCell("reminderQueryQuestion");
table.addCell("reminderQueryAnswer");
table.addCell("graceLoginCount");
table.addCell("screenName");
table.addCell("emailAddress");
table.addCell("facebookId");
table.addCell("openId");
table.addCell("portraitId");
table.addCell("languageId");
table.addCell("timeZoneId");
table.addCell("greeting");
table.addCell("comments");
table.addCell("firstName");
table.addCell("middleName");
table.addCell("lastName");
table.addCell("jobTitle");
table.addCell("loginDate");
table.addCell("loginIP");
table.addCell("lastLoginDate");
table.addCell("lastLoginIP");
table.addCell("lastFailedLoginDate");
table.addCell("failedLoginAttempts");
table.addCell("lockout");
table.addCell("lockoutDate");
table.addCell("agreedToTermsOfUse");
table.addCell("emailAddressVerified");
table.addCell("status");

List<User> totalUsers=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0,numOfUser);                                                   //fetch whole table in our object
Iterator<User> it=totalUsers.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    User eachRow=(User) it.next();
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String str=null;
    java.util.Date jDate=null;

    table.addCell(eachRow.getUuid());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getUserId()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getCompanyId()+"");
    jDate=eachRow.getCreateDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);       
        System.out.println("str modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);
    jDate=eachRow.getModifiedDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);       
        System.out.println("str modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getDefaultUser()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getContactId()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getPassword());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getPasswordEncrypted()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getPasswordReset()+"");
    jDate=eachRow.getPasswordModifiedDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);
        System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";

    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getDigest());
    Iterator itr=(eachRow.getReminderQueryQuestions()).iterator();
    Object obj=itr.next();
    str=(String)obj;
    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getReminderQueryAnswer());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getGraceLoginCount()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getScreenName());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getEmailAddress());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getFacebookId()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getOpenId());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getPortraitId()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getLanguageId());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getTimeZoneId());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getGreeting());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getComments());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getFirstName());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getMiddleName());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getLastName());
    table.addCell(eachRow.getJobTitle());
    jDate=eachRow.getLoginDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);
        System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getLoginIP());
    jDate=eachRow.getLastLoginDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);
        System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getLastLoginIP());
    jDate=eachRow.getLastFailedLoginDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);
        System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);
    table.addCell(eachRow.getFailedLoginAttempts()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getLockout()+"");
    jDate=eachRow.getLockoutDate();
    if(jDate!=null)
    {
        str=df.format(jDate);
        System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
        str=df.format(jDate);
    }
    else 
      str="NA";
    table.addCell(str);

    table.addCell(eachRow.getAgreedToTermsOfUse()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getEmailAddressVerified()+"");
    table.addCell(eachRow.getStatus()+"");
    }//end of wile

    document.add(table);                                            //adding table to created pdf document
    document.close();                                               //we have to first close the document 
    String fileName="attachment;filename=ashraf.pdf";               //filename 
    res.setContentType("application/pdf");          //setting the content type either application or pdf(Portable Document Format)
    res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, fileName); //
    OutputStream out = res.getPortletOutputStream();
    byte[] downloadBytes = Base64.decode((String) req.getAttribute("fileToDownloadBase64"));
    out.write(downloadBytes);
    baos.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    }   //adminMethod
```

Thanks 
asif aftab

Comment: The wall of code and the context (database etc) add very little to the question and answer. It can be reduced to the relevant part: creating the document and pdfwriter, opening the document and setting the page size.  In the answer the last 2 just need to be switched.  Or you can define the page size in the constructor: `Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(2000, 2600));`

Answer (score 3):

First I ask a question then I am giving the answer. In this post my intention is to just share my experience that what's the problem that I faced and how I get rid off from that problem. 
  In my question I said that the only hitch in my application is that size of first page in not large as I mentioned and other pages are according to my command.
  Now solution is just we have set the page size before document.open() and problem solve.

```
   public class pdfPortlet extends MVCPortlet 
   {    
    public void serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res)
     throws PortletException, IOException 
     {
    if(req.isUserInRole("administrator"))
    {
        try 
        {
            adminMethod(req,res);
        }
        catch (PortalException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SystemException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (DocumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        userMethod(req,res);
    }
}



/**********            adminMethod which can fetch the whole user data from user_ table         
 * @throws SystemException 
 * @throws PortalException 
 * @throws DocumentException 
 * @throws IOException **********/

public void adminMethod(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res) throws PortalException, SystemException, DocumentException, IOException
{
    int numOfUser=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();                                                                 //get the number of users

    String remoteUserId = req.getRemoteUser();                                                                          //getting current user id
    Integer io=Integer.parseInt(remoteUserId);                                                                          //getting current userid
    int currentUserId=io.intValue();                                                                                    //typecasting from Integer to primitive int
    User tblUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(currentUserId);                                                         //will return an object containing element of each row and hence by iterating this element we can get number of columns
                                                                                                                        System.out.println("@@@@@@  tbluser: "+tblUser);
    req.setCharacterEncoding(StringPool.UTF8);
    com.lowagie.text.Document document = new com.lowagie.text.Document();   //blank pdf created 
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);                      //predefine class PdfWriter calls static method getInstance
    document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(2000, 2600));//"this is the difference form my previous code here I use this function before the document.open();
    document.open();                                                //open pdf in write method
    PdfPTable table= new PdfPTable(39);                         //creating a pdf table having 39 columns  
    //document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(2000, 2600));
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    /*  float[] columnWidths = new float[39];
    for(int i=0;i<39;i++)
        columnWidths[i]=10f;
    table.setWidths(columnWidths);*/

    table.addCell("uuid_");
    table.addCell("userId");
    table.addCell("companyId");
    table.addCell("createDate");
    table.addCell("modifiedDate");
    table.addCell("defaultUser");
    table.addCell("contactId");
    table.addCell("password_");
    table.addCell("passwordEncrypted");
    table.addCell("passwordReset");
    table.addCell("passwordModifiedDate");
    table.addCell("digest");
    table.addCell("reminderQueryQuestion");
    table.addCell("reminderQueryAnswer");
    table.addCell("graceLoginCount");
    table.addCell("screenName");
    table.addCell("emailAddress");
    table.addCell("facebookId");
    table.addCell("openId");
    table.addCell("portraitId");
    table.addCell("languageId");
    table.addCell("timeZoneId");
    table.addCell("greeting");
    table.addCell("comments");
    table.addCell("firstName");
    table.addCell("middleName");
    table.addCell("lastName");
    table.addCell("jobTitle");
    table.addCell("loginDate");
    table.addCell("loginIP");
    table.addCell("lastLoginDate");
    table.addCell("lastLoginIP");
    table.addCell("lastFailedLoginDate");
    table.addCell("failedLoginAttempts");
    table.addCell("lockout");
    table.addCell("lockoutDate");
    table.addCell("agreedToTermsOfUse");
    table.addCell("emailAddressVerified");
    table.addCell("status");

    List<User> totalUsers=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0,numOfUser);                                                   //fetch whole table in our object
    Iterator<User> it=totalUsers.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        User eachRow=(User) it.next();
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String str=null;
        java.util.Date jDate=null;

        table.addCell(eachRow.getUuid());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getUserId()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getCompanyId()+"");
        jDate=eachRow.getCreateDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);       
            System.out.println("str modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);
        jDate=eachRow.getModifiedDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);       
            System.out.println("str modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getDefaultUser()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getContactId()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getPassword());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getPasswordEncrypted()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getPasswordReset()+"");
        jDate=eachRow.getPasswordModifiedDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);
            System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";

        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getDigest());
        Iterator itr=(eachRow.getReminderQueryQuestions()).iterator();
        Object obj=itr.next();
        str=(String)obj;
        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getReminderQueryAnswer());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getGraceLoginCount()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getScreenName());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getEmailAddress());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getFacebookId()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getOpenId());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getPortraitId()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getLanguageId());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getTimeZoneId());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getGreeting());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getComments());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getFirstName());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getMiddleName());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getLastName());
        table.addCell(eachRow.getJobTitle());
        jDate=eachRow.getLoginDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);
            System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getLoginIP());
        jDate=eachRow.getLastLoginDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);
            System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getLastLoginIP());
        jDate=eachRow.getLastFailedLoginDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);
            System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);
        table.addCell(eachRow.getFailedLoginAttempts()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getLockout()+"");
        jDate=eachRow.getLockoutDate();
        if(jDate!=null)
        {
            str=df.format(jDate);
            System.out.println("str password modified date: "+str);
            str=df.format(jDate);
        }
        else 
          str="NA";
        table.addCell(str);

        table.addCell(eachRow.getAgreedToTermsOfUse()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getEmailAddressVerified()+"");
        table.addCell(eachRow.getStatus()+"");
        }//end of wile

        document.add(table);                                            //adding table to created pdf document
        document.close();                                               //we have to first close the document 
        String fileName="attachment;filename=ashraf.pdf";               //filename 
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");          //setting the content type either application or pdf(Portable Document Format)
        res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, fileName); //
        OutputStream out = res.getPortletOutputStream();
        byte[] downloadBytes = Base64.decode((String) req.getAttribute("fileToDownloadBase64"));
        out.write(downloadBytes);
        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

}   //adminMethod
```